# How To Extend A DataTemplate to Include an Additional Control

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, tabcontrol

So I've got a style, which does some fancy things to a wpf TabControl, among which it sets a HeaderTemplate that allows users to rename the tab. I've got a style which is based on this template that colors the text based on some parameter, and I would like to add a polygon to the header of each tab depending on some conditions.

So the base style looks like:

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem" x:Key="EditableTabItemStyle" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseTabItemStyle}">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <controls:EditableTabContent Template="{StaticResource EditableTabItemTemplate}"
                                             Content="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and my derived looks like:

```
<Style x:Key="DerivedTabItem"
     BasedOn="{StaticResource EditableTabItemStyle}"
     TargetType="TabItem">
<Setter Property="Foreground">
  <Setter.Value>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StateToColorConverter}">
      <Binding Path="States.State1" />
      <Binding Path="States.State2" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I'm looking to add a polygon to the derived style, preferably without changing the base style at all, so my initial thought was to add a header template:

```
<Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
  <Setter.Value>
      <!-- Old header template -->
      <!-- Polygon -->
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

But that overrides the editable styling. I'm not sure if what I want is even possible, so I'll take that for an answer if need be, but if it can be done, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't amend an existing template. You can either:

- Copy it and add anything you like.
- Modify the original template to include another control that's only displayed under certain conditions (e.g. using a `DataTrigger` or a binding to its `Visibility` property).

  - This control could be something very flexible, such as a `ContentPresenter` that could display all sorts of content by binding it to some placeholder property.

In this case, where the template is so simple, I'd go with the former.

Comment: Damn, I was actively hoping to avoid that. I'll wait a few days to see if anybody has a clever work around, but if not the answer's yours.